# Compact component in subspace is component in ambient space

Tags: general-topology

A curious problem I was asking myself was the following:

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space and let $x \in X$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $X \setminus \{x\}$ (given the subspace topology). If $K$ is a non-empty compact connected component of $(X \setminus \{x\}) \setminus U$, then is $K$ a compact connected component of $X \setminus U$?

I believe this is true when $X \setminus U$ is locally connected since $K$ would then be open as well. But I was wondering if there are other conditions I can impose on $X$ that would allow this conjecture to hold. My intuition assures me (perhaps falsely) that the removal of a point should not be a huge problem since $K$ is compact in $X$ as well. For example, this seems to hold when taking $X = \mathbb{R}$, but I'm having trouble with pinpointing what topological properties are being used to obtain an affirmative answer. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean "Then **is** $V$ is also closed ..."?

Comment: Well, I really mean that $V = (X \setminus \{x\}) \setminus U$ for an open set $U \subset X \setminus \{x\}$ that is also an open set in $X$. Now that I write this out, I think there is a subtle distinction to what I wrote in my original question to what I really mean, so I will make an edit.

Comment: You wrote "Then **if** $V$ is also closed ..." which indicates that some conclusion follows. But there is no.

Comment: Oh I see. I meant that "if $V$ is closed in $X$, then $K$ is a compact connected component of $V$ in $X$". But after my edit, I would really like to draw the conclusion that if $U$ is open in $X$, then $K$ is a compact connected component of $X \setminus U$.

Comment: Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open. Thus since $U$ is open in $X\setminus \{x\}$, it is also open in $X$. There is no "if".

Comment: Yes of course, silly me! I have made another edit to better reflect my question.

Comment: Since $X\setminus U$ is also hausdorff, $(X\setminus \{x\})\setminus U = (X\setminus U)\setminus \{x\}$, and the properties of $K$ are only in respect to $X\setminus U$ or $(X\setminus U)\setminus \{x\}$, $U$ is nothing more than a distraction here. You can just start with $X' = X\setminus U$ in the first place and dispense with any mention of $U$. Also, if $K$ is compact and connected in one superspace, it is compact and connected everywhere. Thus the problem reduces to "If $K$ is a compact connected component of $X\setminus \{x\}$, is it also a component of $X$?"

Comment: This is easily seen to be true if and only if $x$ and $K$ do not lie in the same component of $X$. So the only question left is whether it is possible for $x$ and $K$ to lie in the same component of $X$ when $K$ is a component by itself of $X\setminus \{x\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any space with a dispersion point, e.g. "Cantor's Leaky Tent" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan , is a counterexample. It is connected but the components of $X \setminus \{x\}$ are singletons.

Comment: Ah I see. I should have expected that one can construct some pathological counterexample! I am not familiar with dispersion points so am not sure how common such a point is in general topological spaces. Are there any topological conditions that prevent the existence of a dispersion point?

Comment: Locally connected (as you've already noted). Path-connected (assuming Hausdorff). Can't think of any others.